# Has the US said anything about the alleged UAE support for the RSF?

Tags: united-states, civil-war, united-arab-emirates, sudan

Various news media [in Qatar](https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/sudan-uae-war-arms-trade-rsf) but also [elsewhere](https://adf-magazine.com/2024/01/uae-role-in-sudans-civil-war-draws-criticism/) is full of stories of how the UAE allegedly supports the RSF in Sudan, thus [it is claimed] prolonging the civil war there. The UAE officially seems to [deny](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2024/1/24/uae-denies-sending-weapons-to-sudans-rsf-paramilitary-report) any involvement.

Has the US taken any official position on these allegations of UAE support for the RSF?

Comment: I see the issue has reached some Congresspersons too https://sarajacobs.house.gov/news/documentsingle.aspx?DocumentID=879 "Rep. Sara Jacobs (CA-51), Ranking Member of the House Foreign Affairs Subcommittee on Africa led a coalition of 10 lawmakers urging the United Arab Emirates to end its material support to the Rapid Support Forces (RSF) in Sudan, which is committing mass atrocities, including ethnic cleansing and crimes against humanity - echoing the genocide in Darfur two decades ago."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been brought up in White House press briefings, as well as State Department briefings. In all these occasions, the respondent has avoided specifically calling out the UAE, instead choosing to refer to diplomatic conversations occurring with regional partners more generally.

On [June 1st, 2023](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2023/06/01/background-press-call-on-accountability-for-the-ongoing-violence-in-sudan/?utm_source=link), on a call attributable to a 'Senior Administration Official', the administration said that it was engaging with countries in the region to ensure compliance with sanctions:

> **Q:** Hi.  Thank you so much for doing this.  I was wondering if you could talk a little bit about enforcement of the sanctions and if you expect that there will be any difficulties with that.  Have you had conversations with the UAE, for example, about the enforcement?
> [..]
> **Senior Admin Official:** When we impose sanctions that — where the authorities are from the executive order, we work with Treasury and our diplomats to make sure that there is compliance.
>
> So, if these companies are operating, or have financial flows to — in other countries, then we will engage with those countries to ensure compliance with the sanctions.

In mid-December, during [a press briefing on the situation in Sudan](https://www.state.gov/digital-press-briefing-war-crimes-crimes-against-humanity-and-ethnic-cleansing-determination-in-sudan/), the State Department's Ambassador-at-Large for Global Criminal Justice, Beth Van Schaack, gave this response on the UAE's involvement:

> **Q:**  Hi there.  Hello, Ambassador.  Thanks a lot for doing this
> briefing.  I just wanted to ask:  So a large part of this conflict has
> obviously been the involvement of proxies supplying both sides with
> weapons and in some cases, drones.  And I just wondered, has the U.S.
> managed to speak to anyone in the UAE – in the United Arab Emirates
> about their involvement in providing weapons and drones to the RSF?
> And if so, what kind of pressure are you putting on them?  Could you –
> are there – could there be any punitive measures down the line to help
> prevent this from taking place?
>
> **Ambassador Van Schaack:**  Yeah, thank you, Simon.  We have consistently
> spoken to a number of regional partners about the importance of not
> providing weapons or other materiel to either party to the conflict.
> It will only lead to the escalation.  We need to be moving towards
> peace, not providing materiel that will enable this conflict to
> continue.  I can’t speak to particular conversations – obviously those
> are happening on a confidential basis – but rest assured that we’re
> very focused on that.
>
> We’re also really looking for ways to use some of our many sanctions
> authorities to put pressure on individuals and entities that are
> undermining peace in the region.  So back in May, we announced a new
> executive order – President Biden announced – that will allow for the
> designation of those responsible for targeting civilians and other
> serious human rights abuses.  We have designations under that new
> authority for companies that are generating revenues from or
> contributing to the conflict.  We’ve also been able to use visa
> restrictions on particular individuals and other commanders who are
> engaged in abuses.  So we’re trying to think about financial tools,
> legal tools, documentation tools in order to shed a light on what’s
> happening, but also to really encourage regional parties not to
> exacerbate the conflict by providing arms or materiel to one side or
> another.
>
> And we should remind all parties that there is an existing arms
> embargo that dates back to 2005: Resolution 1591 at the UN Security
> Council.  That embargo remains in place.  And so any weapons that are
> being used in Darfur are in violation of – or being provided to
> parties in Darfur – are in violation of a longstanding arms embargo.
> And so that would trigger UN Charter obligations of all member states.

Later on, [in January](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2024/01/30/press-gaggle-by-principal-deputy-press-secretary-olivia-dalton-and-nsc-coordinator-john-kirby-en-route-west-palm-beach-fl/), the NSC Coordinator John Kirby referred a reporter the State Department's statements when quizzed on the pressure being put on the UAE:

> **Q:** I’ve got — I’ve got one last question on Sudan, if I may. Given all
> the political and diplomatic capital you’re using up in the Middle
> East, are you able to bring any pressure on countries like the United
> Arab Emirates, who we know are backing the RSF that the U.S. has
> accused of ethnic cleansing? Do you have any extra diplomatic clout to
> put pressure on the UAE?
>
> **Kirby:** I would push back on the notion that we’re somehow so
> fixated on what’s going on in the Middle East that we can’t focus on
> other places around the world, including Africa. We continue to be
> engaged diplomatically to make sure to — to do what we can to see that
> the aspirations of the Sudanese people are met and that the — and that
> the violence between these two sides stops.
>
> **Q:** Do you have any examples of what you’re doing on that front,
> including pressuring the UAE?
>
> **Kirby:** You know, I’m sure — I’ll refer you to the State Department
> for details, but we continue to work this diplomatically.

Comment: Yeah, there was some other source that said the Biden admin raised the issue privately with the UAE, but I don't have it on hand now. Ah, here https://foreignpolicy.com/2023/12/20/sudan-civil-war-conflict-washington-congress-special-envoy-biden-africa/ "Asked about the Emirati activities in Amdjarass, a spokesman for the National Security Council said the United States had raised concerns “with all external actors that are suspected of supplying either side of the conflict in Sudan, including the U.A.E.”" Seems a diff quote. (NYT)